# Renko Close Price

Tags: pine-script

I am working on a strategy for TradingView in a Pine script. It is a just a moving average above or below price. My issue is when backtesting I get a green bar, red bar, green bar or vice versa it enters the trade at the open price of the middle bar instead of at the close price of the initial bar. Is there any way to change the `strategy.entry()` to the close?

[Chart Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iI52H.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to change the `strategy.entry()` to the close?

That's unfortunately not possible. From the [TradingView wiki](https://www.tradingview.com/wiki/Strategies):

> There is a broker emulator on TradingView for testing strategies. Unlike real trading, the emulator fills orders only at chart prices, that is why an order can be filled only on next tick in forwardtesting and on next bar in backtesting (or later) after strategy calculated.

This also makes sense from a logical perspective: if your script generates an order when the bar closes, there's no room for it to execute trades in that bar anymore. After all, the bar closed and trading for that time period stopped.

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=4
strategy(...,process_orders_on_close=true)
if(close>open)
   ...
```

Comment: Please explain your answer